# How to install packages to Blenders Python?

Tags: python, pip, blender

I want to create a python script in Blender but i would need a 3rd party package(module) and I am having a hard time installing one... 
I then wanted to install Python pip and use that to install the other one, but no luck with that either.
Do I install pip or do I install the packages directly and how?

P.S. The package I want to install is "Socket"...

Comment: If you mean [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) you don't need to install it — it's a module from the standard library.

Comment: Wow, it actually is. Thanks for that:)